# Getting Enum Description in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am totally new to react and javascript, So it may sound silly So Iam trying to show descriptive info about a enum value in react component. Below is code that I have written and not working

```
export function EmployeeFetcher()
{
   const [employeeData, setEmployeeData] = useState();
   const [employeeId, setEmplpyeeId] = useState();

   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!employeeId.length) {
            setEmployeeData(false);
            return;
        }
        fetch('api/employeeinfoProvider/' + employeeId)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                    setEmployeeData({ employeeType: data })
             });       
       }

    return (
        <Container fluid>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <InputGroup className="mb-3 m-2">
                    <FormControl onChange={(e) => setEmplpyeeId(e.target.value)} value={employeeId}
                        placeholder="Search employee"
                        aria-label="Model Info Id"
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
                    />
                    <InputGroup.Append>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="outline-secondary">Search</Button>
                    </InputGroup.Append>
                </InputGroup>
            </Form>
            {<EmployeeViewer employeeInfoData={employeeData} />}
        </Container>
    );

function EmployeeViewer({ employeeInfoData}) {
    return (<Container> {employeeInfoData.employeeTypes.map(x => <Border key={x}>{EmployeeTypeString(x)}</Border>)}</Container>);
}

function EmployeeTypeString(employeeType) {
    switch (employeeType) {
        case 1:
            return "Manager";
        case 3:
            return "Lead";
        case 4:
            return "Software Engineer";
    }
}
```

I am getting below error in browser, if i try run above code with valid parameters

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Are you trying to import and use these functions in another file?

Comment: I added whole code that I am trying to execute. Its not working

Comment: There is a lot of typo in your example

Comment: Yeah I get it.. my bad. I figured it out it was issue of Border, Seems like intellisense is not working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer you as we would need more code to understand the context.

From the error mentionned above, I think that you are trying to use the function `EmployeeViewer` in another file but you are not exporting it in this file.

You can export it as default and then use it in the other file

---

```
function EmployeeViewer({ employeeInfoData}) {
    return (<Container> {employeeInfoData.employeeTypes.map(x => <Border key={x}>{EmployeeTypeString(x)}</Border>)}</Container>);
}

function EmployeeTypeString(employeeType) {
    switch (employeeType) {
        case 1:
            return "Manager";
        case 3:
            return "Lead";
        case 4:
            return "Software Engineer";
    }
}

export default EmployeeViewer;
//------
// OtherFile.js
import EmployeeViewer from './EmployeeViewer';

function App({ data }) {
  return (<div><EmployeeViewer employeeInfoData={data} /></div>);
}

export default App;
```

---

Or only export this function

```
export function EmployeeViewer({ employeeInfoData}) {
    return (<Container> {employeeInfoData.employeeTypes.map(x => <Border key={x}>{EmployeeTypeString(x)}</Border>)}</Container>);
}

function EmployeeTypeString(employeeType) {
    switch (employeeType) {
        case 1:
            return "Manager";
        case 3:
            return "Lead";
        case 4:
            return "Software Engineer";
    }
}
//------
// OtherFile.js
import { EmployeeViewer } from './EmployeeViewer';

function App({ data }) {
  return (<div><EmployeeViewer employeeInfoData={data} /></div>);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: its not issue of export. they are all in same file. there is something else is wrong in code.